# Focus control inside an UserControl in a Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I have a Form let it's name be **MyForm** and there is a UserControl in the Form, let it's name be **MyUserControl**. I'd like to set focus to a TextBox that is in **MyUserControl**.

So the connection looks like this:

```
- Form ┐
--    UserControl ┐
---            TextBox
```

When `MyForm` shown, also `MyUserControl` is shown and the focus **DOES NOT WORK** with this solution:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainFormV2HWT_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ActiveControl = textBox1;
    }
}
```

**BUT IT WORKS WITH THIS SOLUTION:**

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    // ...

    public TextBox MyTextBox
    {
        get
        {
            return textBox1;
        }
    }

    // ...
}

public class MyForm() : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitalizeComponents();
    }


    private void MyForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ActiveControl = myUserControl.MyTextBox;
    }
}
```

I also tried to set **ActiveControl** to `MyUserControl` first, then in `MyUserControl` set **ActiveControl** to `MyTextBox` but it also doesn't work.

**Question:**

Is my working solution is a nice solution or is there any easier, more nice solution, that's not using `MyTextBox` from `MyForm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, You have to focus user control in the form. Something like this:

```
public class MyForm() : Form
{
    private void MyForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myUserControl.Focus();
    }
}
```

and then in the user control:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    private void MyUserControl _Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       textBox1.Select();
    }
}
```

This seems the only combination (Focus -> Select) which works.

Comment: I've found a more simpler solution after I tried your code.
If I subscribe to `VisibleChanged` event of my `UserControl`, then set `ActiveControl = textBox1`, it works, didn't need more code.

Comment: Good!! Do what you want to make the project working :)